# Mongoose query is not getting executed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to execute the following query which is not happening.There's no error,no output.

```
router.get('/getdetails/:empId',(req,res)=>{
    User.aggregate([
        {$match:{_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5d5a8b83352b262670a4d47b")}},
        {
            $lookup:{
                from:"UserClaim",
                localField:"_id",
                foreignField:"userId",
                as:"claims"
            }
        },{
            $unwind:"$claims"
        }
    ])
    .exec((err,userclaims)=>{
        (err)=>{throw err;},
        (userclaims)=>{
            console.log(userclaims);
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Is any data is there for that given id??

Comment: You are using arrow syntax and not using return how do you think it will work?

Comment: @Subburaj Yes,there's data.This query is working in mongodb terminal but it's not working in mongoose apparently.

Comment: @sreeyachowdary whats the error you are getting? or you are getting nothing while calling this api or in the callback?